# Convert a string to an Android widget

Tags: android-layout

Is it possible to convert a String to an android widget.

For example :

```
   String abc = "RadioButton";
```

I want to use this String `abc` as the android widget.

Comment: Guess i need to use switch case and implement it accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your post for readability. Please note that there needs to be a blank line before a code block such that it is displayed correctly. I also removed the upper-case word in the title - some people consider this as CRYING ;-)